How to delete till end of line in operator-pending mode mapping in vim
I'm implementing a vim plugin that moves the cursor within current line. It extends the function of f. Think of it as something similar to notable-ft. Here is a simplified illustrative example of the plugin (this script can be sourced, you may try the examples below yourself):
function! s:F(char, mode)
    execute "normal! f" . a:char
    if a:mode ==# 'o'
        normal! l
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> f ':<c-u>call <sid>F("' . nr2char(getchar()) . '", "n")<cr>'
onoremap <expr> f ':<c-u>call <sid>F("' . nr2char(getchar()) . '", "o")<cr>'

Example text:
hello world

I'm having difficulty implementing the onoremap correctly.
Denote the caret as cursor position. f in normal mode behaves well, but in operator-pending mode, there's an issue.
hello world
^

After keystrokes dfo, it becomes
 world
^

Good. Buf if after keystrokes dfd, it becomes
d
^

The last character in the line cannot be deleted. The problem is that I cannot set the cursor to one character after the last character in current line, which is at position col('$'). I tried manually :call setpos('.', [bufnr('%'), 1, col('$'), 0]), and :py3 vim.current.window.cursor = (1, 11) (where 11 is the length of "hello world"), but it can't either.
I also attempted to find the answer from the notable-ft repo, but despite having read "vimscript the hard way", I'm really new to vimscript and there're so many codes I cannot understand.
Is there any approach to implement the onoremap without such issue? Thank you so much!
